# Android updated from 5.1.1 to 6.0.1 - customer says app settings got lost

Tags: android, cordova, android-6.0-marshmallow

A customer that uses our hybrid application (Cordova + Sencha Touch) informed us that they updated one of their Samsung devices (AFAIK S6) from Android 5.1.1 to 6.0.1. Our application was still on the device after the update, but all settings from within the application were lost.

We store the settings in 2 ways:

1. written to a Sqlite database table, accessible via Cordova plugin; uses `Activity.getDatabasePath()` for the file
2. written to SharedPreferences (because we need some settings before the webview shows our app), using `Activity.get/setSharedPreferences()`

Among own testing devices, I can use a Nexus 7 (2013) and a Galaxy S6, both running with 5.1.1. But if I update them - how can I tell what might be going wrong and leading to the data loss? I'm trying to narrow down the cause, but I don't know where to start looking. Any suggestions?

Comment: The Sqlite handlers probably call `onUpgrade` and drop and recreate the tables from scratch

Comment: You may check if the data is actually still there by using root permission. Check if in `/data/data/<your packagename>/` everything is still there. If not, then either the android update progress causes the data to be deleted or the application resets the data after upgrading the android version.

Comment: @cricket_007: I can't find any occurence of `onUpgrade` in the plugins code. We use an older version (even before the plugin has been renamed) of https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

---

@xdevs23: none of these devices are rooted.

Comment: I'm referring to native Android Java code. I don't know how `onUpgrade` is translated for Cordova